# Finding principal axes of a plane area.

Tags: trigonometry

I have a problem about the way following formula was derived:

$$\tan 2\theta = -\frac{2I_{xy}}{(I_{xx} - I_{yy})} \tag{1}$$

$I_{xy} =$ product of inertia
$I_{xx} =$ second moment of area about xx axis

My lecturer told we can derive that from,
$$I_{x_1y_1} = \Bigl(\frac{I_{xx}-I_{yy}}{2}\Bigr)\sin2\theta+I_{xy} \cos 2\theta = 0 \tag{2}$$

My question is can we divide every term by $\cos 2\theta$ without knowing that it isn't equal to zero.
Even I didn't, I ended up with something like this.

$$\cos 2\theta \left(\Bigl(\frac{I_{xx} - I_{yy}}{2}\Bigr) \tan 2\theta + I_{xy}\right) = 0 \\  
\implies \quad \cos 2\theta = 0 \qquad \text{or} \qquad \Bigl(\frac{I_{xx} - I_{yy}}{2}\Bigr) \tan 2\theta + I_{xy} = 0 \tag{3}$$

Why do we consider only the second part ??

Comment: Well, if $\cos(2\theta)= 0$, then $\tan(2\theta)=\infty$ which implies $I_{xx}-I_{yy}=0$. Is it possible $I_{xx}=I_{yy}$?

Comment: @Qurultay What about a circle taken origin as center ?  $I_{xx} = I_{yy}$ isn't it?

Comment: I have no idea what $I_{xx}$ and $I_{yy}$ are. I just asked " Is it posible?" and you assert "yes, it's possible". Therefore in the case you mentioned, $\cos(2\theta)=0$ is possible.

Comment: @Qurultay My problem is why most of the books and online resources just use the tangent part.

Comment: I don't know your purpose, but I know that tangent is interpreted as slop of a line. the case $\tan=\infty$ corresponds to horizontal and $\tan=0$ to vertical lines.

Answer (score 1):

Ayubowan!

The answer to your first question "Can we divide every term by $\cos\left(2\theta\right)$?" is "No, you can't". The reason for this is very vividly shown by your own equation (3). Now if we consider the first part, i.e. $\cos\left(2\theta\right)=0$, as a valid solution to our problem of finding the orientation of the principal axes of a plane area, we can conclude that if we rotate the present coordinate system by $45^0$ or $135^0$, the product of inertia of any plane area vanishes. In general, this conclusion is wrong. The only case, for which this conclusion is true, is when the plane area is a square and the present coordinate system coincide with two adjacent sides of the square, and that happens solely by chance. Therefore, the premise or action, we used to derive the above conclusion is wrong or prohibited.

Comment: You mentioned that the only case, that conclusion is true is a square with a coordinate system coincide with two adjacent sides. What about a circle with a coordinate system origin coincide with the center ?

Comment: Yes, of course. That is a very very special case, which I did not want to bring into our little discussion, because, in this case, the angle of rotation can be anything, not only $45^0$ and $135^0$. The other thing is that I did not know how much you know about this subject. But, now I know. Thanks for bringing it up.

Answer (score 0):

$\cos2\theta=0$ when $2\theta=\pm\frac\pi2$, and $\sin2\theta=\pm1$. The equation reduces to

$$\frac{I_{xx}-I_{yy}}2=0.$$

This is coherent with the tangent being infinite. And if $I_{xx}\ne I_{yy}$, $\cos2\theta=0$ is not possible.